# Is there a Drupal 6 equivalent to template_preprocess_taxonomy_term()?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, theming

Is there a Drupal 6 equivalent to the method template_preprocess_taxonomy_term()? I'm looking to add some code that will provide some additional links on my taxonomy term pages and want to keep the code in template.php (don't like code in my templates themselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to eventually figure this out myself. I'm using the following in template.php to identify a taxonomy term page in D6:-

```
<?php
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0)=='taxonomy' && arg(1)=='term') {
    // do something
  }
}
?>
```